# Where do I find grub.cfg for dual boot Windows10 and Ubuntu on external drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, external-hdd

I am a novice to Ubuntu, and not very familiar with Linux. I am trying to create an dual boot external drive with Windows10 and Ubuntu (20.04). I was following the instructions provided by Gavin Youker four years ago, until I got to the part of downloading the grub.cfg file. He apparently loaded it to filedropper, but it is no longer there. Does anyone know where I can find it? Also, reading some other posts, it seems that the one he used (and loaded to filedropper) may be specific to Ubuntu 16.04 so it may not work anyway?

Comment: Your `grub.cfg` file will be found in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` or whatever partition you installed /boot/ to (it'll be / if you didn't create a separate partition for /boot)

Comment: Windows does not work from external removable drives. Is system UEFI or BIOS? Ubuntu installer creates grub.cfg for Ubuntu. But Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs UEFI grub to first drive, usually the internal drive. You need to partition in advance. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Ubuntu Installer uses wrong bootloader location for USB/sdb UEFI installs 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1173457

Comment: As for running windows from an external USB drive, I've that before, albeit may be specific to the computer. The directions provided create separate partitions, first to create the Windows partition and install WIN10- done. In Gavin's post, there were several parts. After the Windows install, Using Ubuntu Live from a USB stick,shrink the Windows partition,create a Bootloader partition, then create/mount new directory to install Grub, add grub.cfg he created/uploaded, but is now gone.There are other partitions to be created after this for swap, portable storage, utilities, etc. Trying this.